# How to get value from two Dropdown list and compare them with if?

Tags: unity-game-engine, if-statement, dropdown

[imagesample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwjEl.png)I'm new to Unity and C#.

1. I want to get value from 2 DropDown like the image I've upload (each DropDown contains value "a" and "b")
2. For example :DropDownLeft text = a, DropDownRight text = b, then "not match", but "a" and "a" or "b" and "b" then "match" message will appear.

Is there any simple tutorial I can read that similar?

Comment: Thanks Magnus for suggest an edit to my post :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need the **reference of both dropdowns**, you can store it like:

```
Dropdown leftDropdown = null;
Dropdown rightDropdown = null;
```

Then you need the **current value of each dropdown**, that you can retrieve doing this:

```
int leftValue = leftDropdown.value;
int rightValue = rightDropdown.value;
```

And finally you need to **compare those values**:

```
private void CompareValues(int newValue)
{
    int leftValue = leftDropdown.value;
    int rightValue = rightDropdown.value;

    if (leftValue == rightValue)
    {
        Debug.Log("Match!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Not Match!");
    }
}
```

But probably you want to compare every time the value changes, that's why you need to call the previous method **every time the value of any of your dropdowns change**. The easiest way to do that is to subscribe your method to the `OnValueChanged` event, like this:

```
private void Awake()
{
    leftDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener((newValue) => { CompareValues(newValue); });
    rightDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener((newValue) => { CompareValues(newValue); });
}
```

So if you put it all together in a single script will look like:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    Dropdown leftDropdown = null;
    Dropdown rightDropdown = null;

    private void Awake()
    {
        leftDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener((newValue) => { CompareValues(newValue); });
        rightDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener((newValue) => { CompareValues(newValue); });
    }

    private void CompareValues(int newValue)
    {
        int leftValue = leftDropdown.value;
        int rightValue = rightDropdown.value;

        if (leftValue == rightValue)
        {
            Debug.Log("Match!");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Match!");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that we are passing an int value to the compare method called `newValue` that we are not using, that's cause we are forced to pass it to match the firm of the listener, cause `OnValueChanged` demands that integer. That value is the new value of the dropdown that changes, but since we get the value of both dropdowns every time, we don't really need to take care of that.

Just to exemplify what I'm trying to say, we can achieve the same result but doing it like this:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    Dropdown leftDropdown = null;
    Dropdown rightDropdown = null;

    private void Awake()
    {
        leftDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener((newValueOnLeft) => { CompareValuesWithRight(newValueOnLeft); });
        rightDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener((newValueOnRight) => { CompareValuesWithLeft(newValueOnRight); });
    }

    private void CompareValuesWithRight(int newValueOnLeft)
    {
        int rightValue = rightDropdown.value;

        if (newValueOnLeft == rightValue)
        {
            Debug.Log("Match!");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Match!");
        }
    }
    private void CompareValuesWithLeft(int newValueOnRight)
    {
        int leftValue = leftDropdown.value;

        if (leftValue == newValueOnRight)
        {
            Debug.Log("Match!");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Match!");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope the names of the variable helps you to understand my point ^^

Comment: @SomeoneWhoLearnHowToCode you're welcome, comment here if something doesn' work, and if it does, mark the answer as correct ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class TestCocok : MonoBehaviour
{
Dropdown leftDropdown = null;
Dropdown rightDropdown = null;
Button cekButton = null;
[SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI teks;

public void Awake()
{
cekButton.onClick.AddListener(()=> { CompareValues();});
leftDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener((newValueOnLeft) 
=> { CompareValuesWithRight(newValueOnLeft); });

rightDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener((newValueOnRight) 
=> { CompareValuesWithLeft(newValueOnRight); });
}

public void CompareValues()
{
    int rightValue = rightDropdown.value;
    int leftValue = leftDropdown.value;

    if (leftValue == rightValue)
    {
        teks.text = "Cocok";
        //Debug.Log("Match!");
    }
    else
    {
        teks.text = "Tidak Cocok";
        //Debug.Log("Not Match!");
    }
}

public void CompareValuesWithRight(int newValueOnLeft)
{
    int rightValue = rightDropdown.value;

    if (newValueOnLeft == rightValue)
    {
        Debug.Log("Match!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Not Match!");
    }
}
public void CompareValuesWithLeft(int newValueOnRight)
{
    int leftValue = leftDropdown.value;

    if (leftValue == newValueOnRight)
    {
        Debug.Log("Match!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Not Match!");
    }
    }
}
```